# Rails Bundle, gems conflicts, best way to solve it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, conflict

I meet trouble using Bundle to resolve gems conflict.

> can't activate builder (~> 2.1.2, runtime) for ["activemodel-3.0.8", "actionpack-3.0.8", "railties-3.0.8"], already activated builder-3.0.0 for ["cucumber-0.10.6"] (Gem::LoadError)

So that means active* are requiring builder v 2.1.2 when cucumber want the version 3.0.0.
Easy, but ...

What i'm supposed to do with this ?
Down grade cucumber ?
I tried a bundle update but ... seams the last version of active model, pack and railties is 3.0.8.
How could I know easily cucumber version compatible with active builder ?

Then, what is the general method to solve this kind of situation in general ?

Answer (score 3):

That's odd; Bundler should lock `builder` to v2.1.2 when examining dependencies.

First, try running `bundle update` to have Bundler re-resolve all your dependencies. This *should* correctly lock builder to v2.1.2.

Failing that, you can force builder v2.1.2 by adding it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem `builder`, `~> 2.1.2'
```

Then run `bundle update builder`. This should add v2.1.2 to your `Gemfile.lock`, which should work fine with Cucumber (it only requires >= 2.1.2).

See Yehuda Katz's recent blog post on [Gem versioning and Bundler](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) for a bit more detail.